# Opengl glubyte array to integer value

Tags: c++, opengl

I've got RGB values stored in a GLubyte array of size 3 and wondering how can I represent the RGB color values as a single integer, so what i want is to combine all 3 values to create an integer representation of the color, can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bit shifts to produce the integer:

```
GLuint get_number(GLubyte const* ptr) {
    // magic numbers for shift sizes are safe because GL types have fixed sizes
    // (8 for GLubyte and 32 for GLuint)
    return ptr[0] << 16 + ptr[1] << 8 + ptr[2];
}
```

And to fill an array back you can use bitmasks:

```
void get_bytes(GLuint number, GLubyte* out) {
    out[0] = (number & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
    out[1] = (number & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
    out[2] = number & 0x0000FF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
int color=(ar[0] << 16) | (ar[1] << 8) | ar[2];
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `GLuint color = ar[0]<<24 | ar[1]<<16 | ar[2]<<8` if he wants to pass it to `glColor3ubv((GLubyte *) &color)`? Or should that depend on endianess? Which makes me think that this is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @Peter `(GLubyte *) &color` is silly when you already have one `GLubyte*` to start with. And it breaks strict aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

`YourInteger = R + G*256 + B*65536`

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'd rather use bit shifts instead of multiply. Also you don't want to sum the values but to a bitwise or.

Comment: Well, we are speaking about glubyte array, so inputs are byte. Anyway, I thought this conception would be easier to grab than bitshifts :)